# Why shiny dashboard is taking too long to load?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

### Objective

Hi, I have two datasets. I want to select one at a time by using `radioButtons` in `shinydashboard`.

### Problem

In the `app.R` file, I first load the two data sets (71 Mb and 103 Mb in size). The following code works and only takes few seconds for app to load:

#### Working Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)

# Global
df10151 <- read.csv("Data/df1015.csv", header = TRUE)
df8051 <- read.csv("Data/df805.csv", header = TRUE)

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Driving States"),
  dashboardSidebar(
     sliderInput("fid", "Frame ID:",
                min = 0, max = 50, value = 3, step = 0.1
    )))

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But when I add the `radioButtons`, it takes forever and doesn't load:

#### Failing Code:

```
library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)
    library(shinydashboard)
    
    # Global
    df10151 <- read.csv("Data/df1015.csv", header = TRUE)
    df8051 <- read.csv("Data/df805.csv", header = TRUE)
    
    # UI
    ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "Driving States"),
      dashboardSidebar(
        radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Select the Dataset (first 5 minutes)"),
                 choices = list("US-101" = df10151, "I-80" = df8051), 
                 selected = NULL),         

        sliderInput("fid", "Frame ID:",
                    min = 0, max = 50, value = 3, step = 0.1
        )))
    
    # Server
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
     
    
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

There is no error message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with the radio button. You can't pass a dataset to the choice option. Please look at http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/radio-buttons.html

Comment: @Divi This app is incomplete yet. I want to select one out of the 2 datasets and then plot some part of it. For selection I am using `radioButtons`

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't load" - what doesn't load?

Comment: You probably don't want to include your huge dataset in your radiobutton. Just put the 2 texts then based on the selected text, select the dataset

Comment: @Symbolix, The app doesn't load once I click the "Run App" button in RStudio.

Comment: Yes, exactly as @HubertL says - don't use `list("US-101" = df10151, ...` - **df10151** is your data set. You probably want `list("US-101" = 1, ...`, then use a `switch` or `if` to select the dataset you're plotting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you would like to plot, so here is an example:

Radiobutton in `ui.R` will work like:

```
radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Select the Dataset (first 5 minutes)"),
                 choices = c("US-101" = 1, "I-80" = 2), 
                 selected = 1)
```

For `server.R` you need something like:

```
output$plot = renderPlot({ 
       switch(input$radio,
       `1` = hist(df10151$Var),
       `2` = hist(df8051$Var)
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I was confused about the choices.

Comment: I am assuming you know that the `plot` object needs to be placed in the `dashboardBody()`. You can play with `fluidRow` and `box` to get your desired result.